# How can i change the Vaadin page URL in Spring Boot?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, vaadin, vaadin7

I have a vaadin page for manage my items of my website . The client front-end i use spring boot with JSP view , controller but the manager's i want to try vaadin . Both of them are in one server . So how can i custom the vaadin url .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have had the solution for myself.
Just add `vaadin.servlet.url-mapping=/path` in properties file
or define `@SpringUI(path="/manager")` on head of UI Class.

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about this URL "http://localhost:8080/ ", then in your *application.properties* file, you can write **server.port = 'your port number other than 8080'**. That will work.

Comment: No after that .